# AWS SDK cognito Custom Challenge (Missing required parameter ANSWER)

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

Am using AWS SDK nodejs, currently doin CUSTOM CHALLENGE with phone number as USERNAME.
Able to receive SMS using "**InitiateAuth** "

Request:

```
   const input: Cognito.InitiateAuthCommandInput = {
            ClientId: process.env['Cognito_clientId'],
            AuthFlow: Cognito.AuthFlowType.CUSTOM_AUTH,
            AuthParameters: {
                USERNAME: phoneNo               
            },
        };
```

Response:

```
{
    "result": {
        "$metadata": {
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "requestId": "3b657d1e-0bc9-4688-8d8d-262a15423f61",
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        },
        "ChallengeName": "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE",
        "ChallengeParameters": {
            "USERNAME": "+60xxxxxxx"
        },
        "Session": "AYABeET-_lEjNtSjk92wys9dJeIAHQABAAdTZXJ2aWNlABBDb2duaXRvVXNlclBvb2xzAAEAB2F3cy1rbXMAUGFybjphd3M6a21zOmFwLXNvdXRoZWFzdC0xOjAzMTU3NzI0MDA0ODprZXkvYmEwNzA1YzktMTI0Mi00ODg1LWJhMmYtNDhiMWNjYTNiNDNmALgBAgEAeMtRirmB1qptVeI5EWSyPpLL6RXz-VVK9JVsLMBfSNNmAap9HYRwVToFU4Xvt9DcvfoAAAB-MHwGCSqGSIb3DQEHBqBvMG0CAQAwaAYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMB4GCWCGSAFlAwQBLjARBAxjxbxqrEx0kP7n7g4CARCAO6LG6jTd1lWHaNb69h-_ot85fKE-RWSBUn0NbAHZY06v7HNclPRTei8NIncvXzIUGMzibmSl9OE05hotAgAAAAAMAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGX9wUB-dnBMvCx0hTb_xfD_____AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAPNDFLwOwHcyee5zQVZ4C5oGGEw0k730misyMIysJEg4ZpKkKTdbKMHg8FJgqhlw14UmTk-y-AJqUAr3yu7XhiPhM38Aa3DKxKGPtIDxt0aKZZyPga2RVIVhA0oW_UNlbU9TRzPoG7qph1HhCCTY6XTrT8nNFtGVyuUoPLh4lrUT-3BMQwVphz6oyxrUD8kUvD-tGjyKYhStn6Tljv3ooymkHNv3CGSY93W4KNzQPM410ld24nhJXE1D_gJNhtFQblCepVKf_54BrTNQqcbTSAwZ6o28yIEHEyUYlbK1OYN70vwB1k17uPeOxfVf3YW3xisLItnIn4eAX5UwYjiJSABl-kO2"
    }
}
```

Based on documentation, should be calling "**RespondToAuthChallenge**" API next. But keep getting "Missing required parameter ANSWER"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RespondToAuthChallenge.html

Request:

```
const input: Cognito.RespondToAuthChallengeCommandInput = {
            ClientId: process.env['Cognito_clientId'],
            ChallengeName: ChallengeNameType.CUSTOM_CHALLENGE,
            ChallengeResponses: {
                USERNAME: phoneNo
            },
            Session: body.session
        };
```

Response:

```
InvalidParameterException: Missing required parameter ANSWER
```

Any idea what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What `privateChallengeParameters` does your Create Auth Lambda trigger return?

Answer (score 0):

Add ANSWER to your ChallengeResponses object that you send in to `RespondToAuthChallenge`:

```
const input: Cognito.RespondToAuthChallengeCommandInput = {
        ClientId: process.env['Cognito_clientId'],
        ChallengeName: ChallengeNameType.CUSTOM_CHALLENGE,
        ChallengeResponses: {
            USERNAME: phoneNo,
            ANSWER: /*add sms code or similar here..*/
        },
        Session: body.session
    };
```